# I seem to have multiple versions of ruby on my mac. Is it safe to clean up and remove some?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rvm

In a tutorial project I have started, when i type 'rake db:create' or 'where rake' i get a 'rake aborted! stack level too deep' error.

If i type 'where ruby' in my snow leopard terminal, I get the following:

```
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
/Users/xxx/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

The usr/bin/ruby is an alias that points to: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby

As I only have one project and it uses the rvm ruby, which versions of ruby is it safe for me to delete and what's the best way to go about it? Which files and folders should go?

And where should i check for correct paths? I have the following line in .zshrc:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Is that all that is needed?

Comment: I would recommend, if it's not too much of a pain to just remove all of them, and then proceed with a clean install with rvm.

Comment: Thanks @adivasile. I don't trust myself to reinstall everything properly so i'll just delete the usr/local/bin version for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two might actually be the same since `/Users/xxx/.rvm/bin/ruby` is a symlink to `rvm`'s default Ruby. The third one is the system Ruby which you probably want to leave alone. The one in `/usr/local/bin` should be completely save to remove.

Comment: Cheers @MichaelKohl. I'll play it safe and follow your advice but out of interest, are there any risks involved in deleting the system Ruby?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/194051/how-to-completely-remove-ruby-ruby-gems-on-mac-os-x-10-6-4 Look at the first answer there :-)